# How to size images independent of device?

Tags: resolution, pixel, screenshot, ms-paint

I’m a writer and I just bought a Microsoft Surface. I often have to size images with exact dimensions to fit themes. For example, I write for a site where the images have to be exactly 1345 pixels wide. So far, I used do this:

1. Take screenshot (*print screen* key)
2. Open MS Paint
3. Crop/Resize image so that the pixel count on the bottom matches what I want.

Now with my new Microsoft Surface, I’m facing a weird problem. 1345 pixels on my new screen is much smaller than what I’m used to! So if I take a screenshot on Surface, paste it into MS Paint, and crop it to 1345 pixels, the portion of the screen it captures is ridiculously low.

What do I do now? I thought pixels were fixed width. So now what measure do I use to ensure that my images are the same “size” regardless of what computer I’m using? How do I replicate 1345 pixels on my Surface to capture the same screen area that it used to on my old laptop on MS Paint?

If I need to use another software, I’d prefer to use something simple without a gazillion options, since the only thing I really need to do is crop/resize.

Answer (score 0):

Pixels are a set size (1 Pixel), the question is how many PPI your screen has.

So 72x72 pixel image, on a 72 PPI screen will take up: 1 inch.

That same image on a screen that's 216 PPI (Microsoft Surface Pro 3) will still be 72x72 pixels, but will only cover a third of that space on that screen,  1/3 inch.

Comment: So is there a measurement that consistently gets the same portion of the screen regardless of device? I tried using inches, but when I downloaded some older images of mine, they were smaller on my screen than they were on my previous computer!

Comment: @BhagwadPark were they actually smaller, or did they just occupy lest space on the screen itself? (since it is most likely a higher PPI)

Comment: Less space on the screen itself. But that means I can't trust pixel width since it seems to be device dependent. And I can't trust inches/cm either since the size changes depending on the device! Which measurement can I trust to work independently of screen, device, resolutions etc?

Comment: @BhagwadPark you would create your artwork using a high resolution (>300 PPI) and *(I think)* it automatically adjust it for the screen being viewed on.

Comment: @BhagwadPark No, there is no way to always guarantee picture filling same are on screen without problems. You should not at all begin to think this way. However you can instruct the browser or application to scale the image but it not without problems.